# Use a SQL 2005 table as attribute data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server

We have financial data in a SQL 2005 database which we would like to link to a cadastral shapefile in QGIS. The idea is to be able to display up-to-date outstanding balances for each plot.

How can we link QGIS to the SQL table?

We are using QGIS 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try to get data inside QGIS:

1. The button 'Add MSSQL Server Layer'
2. The button 'Add vector layer', Source type set to Database, Database type set to MSSQL
3. The button 'Add vector layer', Source type set to ODBC
4. Export data as CSV from MSSQL and open the CSV file in QGIS

Once the attribute data is inside QGIS it can be linked to a Shape file with the Properties > Join tab, and then ready for styling.